# Linux output of cronjob handled by php script

Tags: php, linux, cron

Is it possible to let the output of a cronjab be handled by a PHP script? The default is cron sending an email, an alternative is to write it to a log file. But I would like the output being caught by a PHP script doing something with the output (for example store it in a database or send through the Facebook messenger to someone).

Comment: Yes you can. you can use the `>` shell operator to redirect output to a different command (in your case the php script)

Comment: Arsenio, that's incorrect. Using `>` you will pipe the output to a file, not to a command. To pipe it to a command one have to use `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that by piping the output to a php script.

Consider the following example.

test.php:

```
<?php

while (false !== ($line = fgets(STDIN))) {
    var_dump($line);
}
```

Testing it:

```
# echo "this is a random text" | php test.php

/Users/nikola/test.php:4:
string(22) "this is a random text
"
```

Answer (score 0):

The last portion of a line in crontab is the shell script that is run.

The STDOUT of that script is sent to the user's email.

Like any other shell script, you can redirect STDOUT somewhere else using the pipe character.

```
* * * * * do_something_a_lot | php /path/to/your/script.php
```